# Removing Recurring Profiles

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, customer-account, recurring

We are into the fine tuning process of our webshop. So I was scrolling down the customer profile page with my test account and I saw *recurring profiles*

I looked it up and we have decided we don't need it.Now the question:

**How do I turn this off?**

[***I found a thread***](http://lucdebrouwer.nl/how-to-disable-billing-agreements-and-recurring-profiles-in-magento/) of [magento-1.4](/questions/tagged/magento-1.4) saying you have to manually disable this function. But I'd rather not manually destroy a function unless I really have to. So:

**Could anyone tell me if I still need to disable this function manually, or if [magento-1.9](/questions/tagged/magento-1.9) has a built in option to do that?**

Comment: do u want to remove the billing agreement link and recurring profile link from the customer my account links ?

Comment: Yes, but without 'destroying' the code (if possible ofcourse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a small module for this.follow the following steps

**Step 1**: Create a xml file in the `app/etc/modules/Neo_CustomerNavigationLinks.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<config>
    <modules>
        <Neo_CustomerNavigationLinks>
            <active>true</active> 
            <codePool>local</codePool> 
        </Neo_CustomerNavigationLinks>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step 2**: create a xml file in the `app/code/local/Neo/CustomerNavigationLinks/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<config>
    <modules>
        <Neo_CustomerNavigationLinks>
            <version>0.0.1</version> 
        </Neo_CustomerNavigationLinks>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customernavigationlinks>
                    <file>neo_customernavigationlinks.xml</file> 
                </customernavigationlinks>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <account_navigation>Neo_CustomerNavigationLinks_Block_Account_Navigation</account_navigation> 
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <customernavigationlinks>
                <class>Neo_CustomerNavigationLinks_Helper</class> 
            </customernavigationlinks>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Step 3**: Create `app/code/local/Neo/CustomerNavigationLinks/Block/Account/Navigation.php`

```
<?php
class Neo_CustomerNavigationLinks_Block_Account_Navigation extends Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation
{
    public function removeLinkByName($name)
    {
        unset($this->_links[$name]);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Step 4**: Create `app/code/local/Neo/CustomerNavigationLinks/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php
class Neo_CustomerNavigationLinks_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

**Step 5**: Create `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/neo_customernavigationlinks.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<layout>
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="removeLinkByName">
                <name>billing_agreements</name> 
            </action>
            <action method="removeLinkByName">
                <name>recurring_profiles</name> 
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
</layout>
```

Clear cache and see you have done.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this first! This probably answers that Magento still can't disable this option on its own.

Comment: Ofcourse, I pressed [enter] too fast to add that to my comment ;)

Comment: Does this extensions use the shopstandard language as reference to delete the right fields? Or are these fields standard Magento and doesn't it matter what they are called? Language is Dutch.

Comment: it is not depened not use any other extensions.it take the name of the link which u want to remove and passes to the function and function removes the link thats it

Comment: A side note - you should not include closing `?>` in PHP only files.  See [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html).

Comment: @GrayleBV my answer worked for you ?

Comment: No it doesnt work. This is what I've done: 1) Created all files like noted above. 2) Placed all files in the appropriate folders. 3) cleared the Magento cache (var/cache), cleared the Magento cache in the back-end and cleared my browser cache. 4) I relogged on my user account in the front end. They are still there.

Comment: And I did the same ritual after removing the `?>` extension inside the `.php` files.

Comment: check wther you are missing anything

Comment: I have a folder: app/code/local/Neo/CustomerNavigationLinks. There are 3 other folders in that folder: block/account, etc and helper. `/block/account` includes `navigation.php`; `/etc` includes `config.xml`; `/helper` includes data.php; Then the `Neo_customernavigationlinks.xml` file in `app/etc/modules` and the `neo_customernavigationlinks.xml` file is placed inside the `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\` folder.

Comment: @GrayleBV Block folder should be like this Block not like block similar helper should be Helper like Helper.bascally u are folder names and file names should be same as i had pasted in the answer

Comment: It's case sensitive. Gonna change it now.

Comment: Changed, and double checked. Cleared Magento cache and \var\cache folder. I am currently using a local server to test... It's not working.

Comment: u need to check everything like a single space in the xml file wont run the code

Comment: It is exactly the same as you noted it, same foldes, same file names and same content...

Comment: Could it be due to the local server? It shouldn't matter though...

Comment: no.localhost or server doesnt matters

Comment: So we've hit a brick wall ;). Any suggestions?

Comment: give your code so that i can findout

Comment: Check the question!

Comment: In app/code/local/Neo/CustomerNavigationLinks/etc/config.xml do u have </config> on the last line ?

Comment: Nope, that was missing ;). Cheers mate!

Comment: now worked right ?

Comment: can you also give the upvote

Comment: Can't do upvote sadly... need 15 rep. Sorry (Can't push that button any harder)!